# Error when I try to load a previous save on my program

Tags: python

Whenever I try to load a previous game on this program I get an error. The save function from the menu is meant to load values in the game such as gold amount, chest amount and bandit amount that would then be used in a session as a why to "load" a previous game. I'm also not sure if the pickle module is suitable for this as there should be another way of doing this but I wanted to try pickle as it was recommended for this kind of function.

```
import random
import sys
import time
import os
import pickle #module used to serielize objects
boardeasy=[]
boardmed=[]
boardhard=[]
current=[0,0]
treasures = [(random.randint(0,8), random.randint(0,8)) for i in range(12)]
bandits = [(random.randint(0,8), random.randint(0,8)) for i in range(12)]
Coins = 0
Chest = 10
Bandit1 = 5
Bandit2 = 7
Bandit3 = 10

class user():
    def __init__(self, username, userscore, usertime):
        self.username = username
        self.userscore = userscore
        self.usertime = usertime

#For loop prints a new 8*8 grid after every move
boardeasy = [[' ' for j in range(8)] for i in range(8)]
def table_game_easy():
    print("  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8")
    print("---------------------------------")
    for row in range(8):
        print ('| ' + ' | '.join(boardeasy[row][:8]) + ' | ' + str(row + 1))
        print("---------------------------------")
    treasures_row = [random.randint(0,8) for i in range(10)]
    treasures_col = [random.randint(0,8) for i in range(10)]
    bandits_row = [random.randint(0,8) for i in range(5)]
    bandits_col = [random.randint(0,8) for i in range(5)]

# For loop prints a new 10*10 grid after every move
boardmed = [[' ' for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]

def table_game_meduim():
    print("  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10")
    print("------------------------------------------")
    for row in range(10):
        print ('| ' + ' | '.join(boardmed[row][:10]) + ' | ' + str(row + 1))
        print("------------------------------------------")
    treasures_row = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(10)]
    treasures_col = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(10)]
    bandits_row = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(7)]
    bandits_col = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(7)]

# For loop prints a new 12*12 grid after every move
boardhard = [[' ' for j in range(12)] for i in range(12)]
def table_game_hard():
    print("  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12")
    print("----------------------------------------------------")
    for row in range(12):
        print ('| ' + ' | '.join(boardhard[row][:12]) + ' | ' + str(row + 1))
        print("----------------------------------------------------")
    treasures_row = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(10)]
    treasures_col = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(10)]
    bandits_row = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(10)]
    bandits_col = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(10)]

#this function is in charge of downwards movement
def down(num,lev):
    num=(num+current[0])%lev#The % formats this equation
    current[0]=num
#this function is in charge of downwards movement
def right(num,lev):
    num=(num+current[1])%lev #The % formats this equation
    current[1]=num
#this function is in charge of downwards movement
def left(num,lev):
    if current[1]-num>=0:
        current[1]=current[1]-num
    else:
        current[1]=current[1]-num+lev
#this function is in charge of downwards movement
def up(num,lev):
    if current[0]-num>=0:
        current[0]=current[0]-num
    else:
        current[0]=current[0]-num+lev

def easy_level(Coins, Chest, Bandit1):
    #This function is for the movement of the game in easy difficulty
    while  True and Chest > 0:
        oldcurrent=current
        boardeasy[oldcurrent[0]][oldcurrent[1]]='*' 
        table_game_easy()
        boardeasy[oldcurrent[0]][oldcurrent[1]]=' '
        n = input('Enter the direction followed by the number Ex:Up 5 , Number should be < 8 \n')
        n=n.split()
        if n[0].lower() not in ['up','left','down','right']:#Validates input
            print('Wrong command, please input again')
            continue
        elif n[0].lower()=='up':
            up(int(n[1].lower()),8)#Boundary is set to 8 as the 'easy' grid is a 8^8
        elif n[0].lower()=='down':
            down(int(n[1].lower()),8)
        elif n[0].lower()=='left':
            left(int(n[1].lower()),8)
        elif n[0].lower()=='right':
            right(int(n[1].lower()),8)

        print(Chest,"chests left")
        print(Bandit1,"bandits left")
        print("Coins:",Coins)#Acts as a counter, displays the number of coins that the player has
        if (current[0], current[1]) in treasures[:8]:
            Chest = Chest - 1
            print("Hooray! You have found booty! +10 gold")
            Coins = Coins + 10 #Adds an additional 10 points
            print("Coins:",Coins)


        if (current[0], current[1]) in bandits[:8]:
            Bandit1 = Bandit1 - 1
            print("Oh no! You have landed on a bandit...they steal all your coins!")
            Coins = Coins-Coins #Removes all coins
            print("Coins:",Coins)

        boardeasy[current[0]][current[1]]='*'#sets value to players position

    username = input("Please enter a username:")    
    with open("high_scores.txt","a") as f:
        f.write(str(Coins)+ os.linesep)
        f.write(username + os.linesep)
        f.close()

def med_level(Coins, Chest, Bandit2):
#This function is for the movement of the game in medium difficulty
    while  True:
        oldcurrent=current

        boardmed[oldcurrent[0]][oldcurrent[1]]='*'
        table_game_meduim()
        boardmed[oldcurrent[0]][oldcurrent[1]]=' '
        n = input('Enter the direction followed by the number Ex:Up 5 , Number should be < 10 \n')
        n=n.split()
        if n[0].lower() not in ['up','left','down','right']:
            print('wrong command')
            continue
        elif n[0].lower()=='up':
            up(int(n[1].lower()),10)#Boundary is set to 10 as the 'easy' grid is a 10^10
        elif n[0].lower()=='down':
            down(int(n[1].lower()),10)
        elif n[0].lower()=='left':
            left(int(n[1].lower()),10)
        elif n[0].lower()=='right':
            right(int(n[1].lower()),10)
        print(Chest,"chests left")
        print(Bandit2,"bandits left")
        print("Coins:",Coins)#Acts as a counter, displays the number of coins that the player has
        if (current[0], current[1]) in treasures[:10]:
            Chest = Chest - 1
            print("Hooray! You have found booty! +10 gold")
            Coins = Coins+10 #Adds an additional 10 points
            print("Coins:",Coins)

        if (current[0], current[1]) in bandits[:10]:
            Bandit2 = Bandit2 - 1
            print("Oh no! You have landed on a bandit...they steal all your coins!")
            Coins = Coins-Coins #Removes all coins
            print("Coins:",Coins)
        boardmed[current[0]][current[1]]='*'

def hard_level(Coins, Chest, Bandit3):
#This function is for the movement of the game in hard difficulty
    while  True:
        oldcurrent=current
        boardhard[oldcurrent[0]][oldcurrent[1]]='*'
        table_game_hard()
        boardhard[oldcurrent[0]][oldcurrent[1]]=' '
        n = input('Enter the direction followed by the number Ex:Up 5 , Number should be < 12 \n')
        n=n.split()
        if n[0].lower() not in ['up','left','down','right']:
            print('wrong command')
            continue
        elif n[0].lower()=='up':
            up(int(n[1].lower()),12)#Boundary is set to 12 as the 'hard' grid is a 12^12
        elif n[0].lower()=='down':
            down(int(n[1].lower()),12)
        elif n[0].lower()=='left':
            left(int(n[1].lower()),12)
        elif n[0].lower()=='right':
            right(int(n[1].lower()),12)

        print(Chest,"chests left")
        print(Bandit3,"bandits left")
        print("Coins:",Coins)#Acts as a counter, displays the number of coins that the player has
        if (current[0], current[1]) in treasures[:12]:
            Chest = Chest - 1
            print("Hooray! You have found booty! +10 gold")
            Coins = Coins+10 #Adds an additional 10 points
            print("Coins:",Coins)

        if (current[0], current[1]) in bandits[:12]:
            Bandit2 = Bandit2 - 1
            print("Oh no! You have landed on a bandit...they steal all your coins!")
            Coins = Coins-Coins #Removes all coins
            print("Coins:",Coins)

        boardhard[current[0]][current[1]]='*'
def instruct():
    difficulty = input("""Before the game starts, please consider what difficulty
would you like to play in, easy, medium or (if you're brave) hard.
""")
    if difficulty == "easy":
        print("That's great! Lets continue.")
        time.sleep(1)#Allows the user time to get ready
        print("initiating game in...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print()
        print("3")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("2")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("1")
        time.sleep(1)
        for i in range(3):
            print("")
        easy_level(Coins, Chest, Bandit1)

    elif difficulty == "medium":
        print("That's great! Lets continue.")
        time.sleep(1)#Allows the user time to get ready
        print("initiating game in...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print()
        print("3")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("2")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("1")
        time.sleep(1)
        for i in range(3):
            print("")
        med_level(Coins, Chest, Bandit2)

    elif difficulty == "hard":
        print("That's great! Lets continue.")
        time.sleep(1)#Allows the user time to get ready
        print("initiating game in...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print()
        print("3")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("2")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("1")
        time.sleep(1)
        for i in range(3):
            print("")
        hard_level(Coins, Chest, Bandit3)
    else:
       print("Sorry, that is an invalid answer. Please restart the programme")

def menu():
    #This function lets the user quit the application or progress to playing.
    print("")
    print ("Are you sure you wish to play this game? Please answer either yes or no.")
    choice1 = input() # Sets variable to user input
    if choice1.lower().startswith('y'): 
       print("Okay lets continue then!")
       print("")
       print("")
       print("""~~~~~~~~~~MENU~~~~~~~~~~
             1). Load a previous game
             2). Display the high score table
             3). Continue

             """)
       choice2 = input(">")
       while choice2 != '3':
           print("")
           print("")
           print("""~~~~~~~~~~MENU~~~~~~~~~~
             1). Load a previous game
             2). Display the high score table
             3). Continue

             """)
           choice2 = input(">")
           if choice2 == "1":
               with open('savefile.dat', 'rb') as f:
                   (Coins, Chest, Bandit1) = pickle.load(f)

           elif choice2 == "2":
               with open("high_scores.txt") as f:
                   for line in f:
                       print(line)
                       print("")

    elif choice1.lower().startswith('n'):
        print("Thank you, I hope you will play next time!")
        print("")
        quit("Thank you for playing!")#Terminates the programme
    else:
        print("Sorry, that is an invalid answer. Please restart the programme")
        print("")
        quit()

    instruct()

def showInstructions():
    time.sleep(1.0)
    print("Instructions of the game:")
    time.sleep(1.0)
    print("""
You are a treasure hunter, your goal is to collect atleast 100 gold by the end
of the game from treasure chests randomly scattered across the grid. There are
10 chests within a grid (this can be changed based on difficulty) and  each
treasure chest is worth 10 gold but can only be reclaimed 3 times before it is
replaced by a bandit. Landing on a bandit will cause you to lose all of your
gold and if all the chests have been replaced by bandits and you have less then
100 gold this means you lose!
Press enter to continue...""")
    input()

    print("""
At the start of the game, you always begin at the top right of the grid.
Below is a representation of the game:

 * 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Press enter to continue...""")
    input()

    print("""
When deciding where to move, you should input the direct co-ordinates of your
desired location. For instance:
Enter the direction followed by the number Ex: Up 5 , Number should be < 8
right 3
 0 0 0 * 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Unlucky move! You have found nothing!
If nothing on the grid changes , this means that your move was a bust! Landing
on nothing isn't displayed on the grid.
Press enter to continue...""")
    input()
    print("""
Enter the direction followed by the number Ex: Up 5 , Number should be < 8
down 4
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 * 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Hooray! You have found booty! +10 gold
Here you can see that the use has landed on a chest!
As you land on chest, they get replaced by bandits. Be sure to remember the
previous locations so you don't accidently land on a bandit and lose all
your gold!
Press enter to continue...""")
    input()

#Introduces the user
print('Welcome to the Treasure hunt!')
time.sleep(0.3)
print()
time.sleep(0.3)
print('Would you like to see the instructions? (yes/no)')
if input().lower().startswith('y'):#If function checks for the first letter
    showInstructions()
elif input == 'no' or 'No':
    print("Lets continue then!")#Calls the function which displays instructions
else:
   print("Please check your input and try again.")

menu()
```

Comment: can you tell us what error message you get?

Comment: you forgot to include the part where you save the file. You only added loading, so we can't verify your code.

Comment: unrelated `[random.randint(0,10) for i in range(10)]`   ==>  `random.choices(range(11),k=10)` .. done - it returns your list

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve], providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue. Especially interest are load and save methods - condensed into a minimal example - not your whole source code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`pickle` is not the best format for that. I suggest using the popular `json` format.

To save a file:

```
with open('somefile.sav', 'w') as f:
    json.dump([coins, chests, bandits], f)
```

To load again:

```
with open('somefile.sav') as f:
    coins, chests, bandits = json.load(f)
```